# ASP.NET MVC AsyncController continue browsing while waiting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asynccontroller

I want to use jQuery ajaxForm to post data to an AsyncController to fire off some task. I want the user to be able to continue browsing to other pages while this task completes. I then want to display a status message using something like [jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html) once the task has completed.

Does anyone think this is possible?

First issue, does the callback action xxxCompleted fire when leaving the page that called xxxAsync?

Second issue, how would you retrieve the JsonResult returned from xxxCompleted to display in the UI (via jGrowl for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible assuming "browsing other pages" is obviously in the context of your own site.  You can do the "traditional" poll of the server via ajax or take a look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or the new [SignalR](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SignalR) just released.